Sum of future payments in one column and show current month payment in another column
I have a dataset with id, monthly payments for current and future months, branch, address, city and country. I need to show all columns with future monthly payments summed up and current month payment shown in next column like below
Source data



ID
Payments
Branch
Address
City
Country
TranDate




100
25
B1
Axyz
C2
Cty  2
1-Feb


100
25
B1
Axyz
C2
Cty  2
1-Mar


100
25
B1
Axyz
C2
Cty  2
1-Apr


100
25
B1
Axyz
C2
Cty  2
1-May


100
25
B1
Axyz
C2
Cty  2
1-Jun


100
10
B1
Axyz
C2
Cty  2
10-Jul


103
33
B2
Bxyz
C3
Cty  3
1-Feb


103
33
B2
Bxyz
C3
Cty  3
1-Mar


103
33
B2
Bxyz
C3
Cty  3
1-Apr


103
11
B2
Bxyz
C3
Cty  3
5-May



**Transformed data **
For example query executed in April for ID 100 will look like below (85 = 25+25+25+10) summation of payments for April + May + June + July
Output for April I need



ID
Cum_fut_Payments
Monthly_payments
Branch
Address
City
Country




100
85
25
B1
Axyz
C2
Cty  2


103
44
33
B2
Bxyz
C3
Cty  3



Output I am getting from my query for April



ID
Cum_fut_Payments
Monthly_payments
Branch
Address
City
Country




100
85
35
B1
Axyz
C2
Cty  2


103
44
44
B2
Bxyz
C3
Cty  3



For ID 100 both monthly payments getting added up (25+10) and ID 103 (33+11) instead Monthly_payments field should show only that month payment - 25 for ID 100 and 33 for ID 103
My query is as below
select ID,sum(payments) as cum_fut_payments, sum(payments) as monthly_payments, branch, address, city, country 
from
 ( select
   ID
   sum(payments) as cum_fut_payments,
   payments as monthly_payments,
   branch,
   address,
   city,
   country
   from
   table 1
   group by
     ID, payments,branch,address,city,country) as A
   group by
     ID, payments,branch,address,city,country

How can I show the desired result with one column summed up all future payments and another column only that month payment?

You can use a CTE to make both tables then join them back on the id. If this something to run in the current month. Otherwise you can pass the month you want in place of MONTH(GETDATE()). Link to SQL Fiddle
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  ID INT,
  Payments INT,
  Branch VARCHAR(255),
  Address VARCHAR(255),
  City VARCHAR(255),
  Country VARCHAR(255),
  TranDate DATE
);

INSERT INTO table1(ID, Payments, Branch, Address, City, Country, TranDate) VALUES (100, 25, 'B1', 'Axyz', 'C2', 'Cty 2', '2024-02-01');
INSERT INTO table1(ID, Payments, Branch, Address, City, Country, TranDate) VALUES (100, 25, 'B1', 'Axyz', 'C2', 'Cty 2', '2024-03-01');
INSERT INTO table1(ID, Payments, Branch, Address, City, Country, TranDate) VALUES (100, 25, 'B1', 'Axyz', 'C2', 'Cty 2', '2024-04-01');
INSERT INTO table1(ID, Payments, Branch, Address, City, Country, TranDate) VALUES (100, 25, 'B1', 'Axyz', 'C2', 'Cty 2', '2024-05-01');
INSERT INTO table1(ID, Payments, Branch, Address, City, Country, TranDate) VALUES (100, 25, 'B1', 'Axyz', 'C2', 'Cty 2', '2024-06-01');
INSERT INTO table1(ID, Payments, Branch, Address, City, Country, TranDate) VALUES (100, 10, 'B1', 'Axyz', 'C2', 'Cty 2', '2024-07-10');
INSERT INTO table1(ID, Payments, Branch, Address, City, Country, TranDate) VALUES (103, 33, 'B2', 'Bxyz', 'C3', 'Cty 3', '2024-02-01');
INSERT INTO table1(ID, Payments, Branch, Address, City, Country, TranDate) VALUES (103, 33, 'B2', 'Bxyz', 'C3', 'Cty 3', '2024-03-01');
INSERT INTO table1(ID, Payments, Branch, Address, City, Country, TranDate) VALUES (103, 33, 'B2', 'Bxyz', 'C3', 'Cty 3', '2024-04-01');
INSERT INTO table1(ID, Payments, Branch, Address, City, Country, TranDate) VALUES (103, 11, 'B2', 'Bxyz', 'C3', 'Cty 3', '2024-05-05');
-- QUERY database
WITH cum_pymts AS(
select
   ID,
   sum(payments) as cum_fut_payments,
   branch,
   address,
   city,
   country
   from
   table1
  WHERE
  trandate >= DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
   group by
     ID, branch,address,city,country
),
current_month_pymt AS(
SELECT
   ID,
   sum(payments) as monthly_payments,
   branch,
   address,
   city,
   country
   from
   table1

   WHERE
   MONTH(trandate) = MONTH(GETDATE())
   group by
     ID, branch,address,city,country
)
SELECT
   a.ID,
   a.cum_fut_payments,
   COALESCE(b.monthly_payments, 0) as monthly_pymts,
   a.branch,
   a.address,
   a.city,
   a.country
FROM cum_pymts a
LEFT JOIN current_month_pymt b ON
   a.id = b.id
   AND
   a.branch = b.branch
   AND
   a.address = b.address
   AND
   a.city = b.city
   AND
   a.country = b.country


the above query do not return the correct value . It give same value for monthly payments and cum payments

@Arun.K i edited my answer. I had payments in the GROUP BY which is now removed

You've not explained how you get the monthly payments value so I've assumed it always the first value. You also did not explain if accounts move branches etc so I made some assumptions.
DECLARE @dt datetime  = '2024-04-01'

DECLARE @t TABLE (ID int, Payments int, Branch varchar(2),  Address varchar(5), City varchar(2),    Country varchar(5),     TranDate  datetime )
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
(100, 25, 'B1', 'Axyz', 'C2', 'Cty 2', '2024-02-01'),
(100, 25, 'B1', 'Axyz', 'C2', 'Cty 2', '2024-03-01'),
(100, 25, 'B1', 'Axyz', 'C2', 'Cty 2', '2024-04-01'),
(100, 25, 'B1', 'Axyz', 'C2', 'Cty 2', '2024-05-01'),
(100, 25, 'B1', 'Axyz', 'C2', 'Cty 2', '2024-06-01'),
(100, 10, 'B1', 'Axyz', 'C2', 'Cty 2', '2024-07-10'),
(103, 33, 'B2', 'Bxyz', 'C3', 'Cty 3', '2024-02-01'),
(103, 33, 'B2', 'Bxyz', 'C3', 'Cty 3', '2024-03-01'),
(103, 33, 'B2', 'Bxyz', 'C3', 'Cty 3', '2024-04-01'),
(103, 11, 'B2', 'Bxyz', 'C3', 'Cty 3', '2024-05-05')

SELECT 
    ID, FCPayments, Payments, Branch, Address, City, Country
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            ID, 
            FCPayments = SUM(Payments) OVER(PARTITION BY ID),
            Payments = FIRST_VALUE(Payments) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY TranDate),
            Branch = FIRST_VALUE(Branch) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY TranDate),
            Address = FIRST_VALUE(Address) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY TranDate),
            City = FIRST_VALUE(City) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY TranDate),
            Country = FIRST_VALUE(Country) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY TranDate),
            TranDate
            FROM @t 
            WHERE TranDate >= @dt
    ) a 
    WHERE MONTH(TranDate) = MONTH(@dt) AND YEAR(TranDate) = YEAR(@dt)


why first value for payments? Requirement is to show cumpayments from current month onwards to future in one column (say cumpayments) and have the current month payment value in another column (payments) along with all other columns

The inner query has a WHERE clause that restricts the transactions to those only >= the 'run date' (@dt), therefore the first value will be the current payment. Change the April payment value to something else and you'll see you get that in the results assuming the 'run date' (@dt) is set to April 1st.


As a default, you can join table by itself as follows:

    SELECT   t1.ID, t1.Payments monthly_payments, t1.Branch, t1.Address, t1.City, t1.Country, t1.TranDate,  t1.Payments monthly_payments, sum(t2.Payments) cum_fut_payments
    FROM     table1 t1, table1 t2
    WHERE    t1.id=t2.id
         and t2.TranDate>=t1.TranDate
    GROUP BY t1.ID, t1.Payments, t1.Branch, t1.Address, t1.City, t1.Country, t1.TranDate


You can also use analytic functions


id fields are repeated though. would need to do a multijoin, or assume a select distinct would remove duplicates.

This query is the surce for outer queries.

This query is the surce for outer queries.  SELECT   ID, Payments monthly_payments, Branch, Address, City, Country, TranDate,  Payments monthly_payments, cum_fut_payments FROM ( SELECT   t1.ID, t1.Payments monthly_payments, t1.Branch, t1.Address, t1.City, t1.Country, t1.TranDate,  t1.Payments monthly_payments, sum(t2.Payments) cum_fut_payments
FROM     table1 t1, table1 t2
WHERE    t1.id=t2.id
and t2.TranDate>=t1.TranDate
GROUP BY t1.ID, t1.Payments, t1.Branch, t1.Address, t1.City, t1.Country, t1.TranDate ) WERE  id=100 AND trandate = :VALUE
